# Can't load images on canvas for my js game

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I am making a mahjong game in js and I have a problem loading images on canvas

1. canvas

   ```
   // Create the canvas
   var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
   var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
   canvas.width = 512;
   canvas.height = 512;
   //draw canvas
   document.body.appendChild(canvas);
   ```
2. Arrays

   ```
   //Array with Tiles & set length to 144 which are the requested tiles
   var tiles = new Array(2);//will be 144
   //2D map array for showing the images coordinates
   var map = [[69,50],[100,150]];//will be 144 coordinates
   ```
3. my function update()

   ```
   function update(){
       for(var i=0;i<tiles.length;i++){
               //make the tile object
       tiles[i] = new Object();    
       tiles[i].id = i ;
       tiles[i].selected = false;
       //set the coordinates from map Array
       tiles[i].x=map[i][0];
       tiles[i].y=map[i][1];
       //tiles[i].ready=false;
                   //These are for the image location works fine
       //convert i to String
       var sourceNumber = i.toString();
       //add .png to String
       var source = sourceNumber.concat(png);
       //add /image
       var source = dest.concat(source);   
       tiles[i].img = new Image();
       tiles[i].img.onload = function(){
           //tiles[i].ready=true;
           ctx.drawImage(tiles[i].img,tiles[i].x,tiles[i].y,xdimension,ydimension);
       };
       tiles[i].img.src = source ;

       }
   }
   ```

I runned it on each of my browser it won't load images , I debugged on chrome and it says on **ctx.drawImage(...);** -> **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'img' of undefined(repeated many times)**, So I tried the **tiles[I].ready** and after load images but still has that error.Any suggestions on how should I implement the loading of the tile images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time `ctx.drawImage` is called, the value for i is 2. The problem is that the for-loop (`for(var i=0;i<tiles.length;i++)`) has finished executing before any of the images have loaded. Consequently, the value of i at the time the onload function is called is the value at which the loop ceased being run. The easiest way around this is to save the index (i) into the img element itself, so that you can retrieve it in the onload handler.

Here's a simple adaption of your code that seems to work just fine.
The important changes are:

1. `tiles[i].img.iVal = i;`
2. and the body of the onload handler.

I also:

**(a)** added an array to hold hard-coded image names for convenience, rather than dynamically creating them (I'd have had to name some images into the format that the code computes)

**(b)** removed the `xdimension` and `ydimension` vars from the `drawImage` call since I dont know what they are.

**(c)** changed `.concat(png)` to `.concat(".png")` since it was easier than declaring a variable called `png` that holds the string `.png`

Anyway, here's the sample-code I used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

var canvas, ctx, tiles, map;

function onDocLoaded()
{
    canvas = newEl('canvas');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = canvas.height = 512;
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);

    tiles = new Array(2);
    map = [[69,50],[100,150]];

    update();
}

var imgFileNames = ["img/girl.png", "img/redbaron.png"];

function update()
{
    for(var i=0;i<tiles.length;i++)
    {
        //make the tile object
        tiles[i] = new Object();    
        tiles[i].id = i ;
        tiles[i].selected = false;
        //set the coordinates from map Array
        tiles[i].x=map[i][0];
        tiles[i].y=map[i][1];
        //tiles[i].ready=false;

        //These are for the image location works fine
        //convert i to String
//      var sourceNumber = i.toString();
        //add .png to String
//      var source = sourceNumber.concat(".png");
        //add /image
//      var source = dest.concat(source);   
        tiles[i].img = new Image();
        tiles[i].img.iVal = i;
        tiles[i].img.onload = 
        function()
        {
            var curI = this.iVal;
            ctx.drawImage(tiles[curI].img,tiles[curI].x,tiles[curI].y); 
            // ctx.drawImage(this,tiles[curI].x,tiles[curI].y); //equiv to above line
        };
        tiles[i].img.src = imgFileNames[i];
    }
}
</script>
<style>
canvas
{
    border: solid 1px red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```